# Update database using JSP

Tags: sql, jsp

I am using following JSP code to update database.It show message "updated successfully", but data does not update in database.!

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.CallableStatement"%>

<%
String ssiteid=request.getParameter("siteid");
String sowner=request.getParameter("owner");
String sstate=request.getParameter("state");
String sdate=request.getParameter("date");
String stariff=request.getParameter("tariff");
String sdiscom=request.getParameter("discom");

  Connection con=null;

try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost > /s3n","root","system");
    PreparedStatement cstmt= con.prepareStatement("update windtariff_master set Owner=?,      State=?, Date=?, Tariff=?, Discom=? where Site_ID=?");

 cstmt.setString(1,ssiteid); 
 cstmt.setString(2,sowner);
 cstmt.setString(3,sstate);
 cstmt.setString(4,sdate);
 cstmt.setString(5,stariff);
 cstmt.setString(6,sdiscom);
 cstmt.executeUpdate(); 
 out.println("updated successfully");
   }
   catch(Exception e){
    out.print("try not allowed"+e);
            }


 %>
```

Comment: "//localhost >  /s3n " what do you mean by this '>' and /s3n ?

Comment: "s3n" is the name of the database the OP is connecting to.

Comment: executeUpdate returns an int, what is the value of the int?

Comment: could you pls paste the stacktrace or exception pls....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you move this code out of scriptlet and into a POJO.  It'll be far easier to test that way.  Test it and put it aside.

Scriptlets in JSPs are a bad way to go.  It's a style that's been discredited for a long time.  Model-2 MVC is far preferred.  If you must go this way, I'd recommend that you learn JSTL and use its `<sql>` tags.

Printing out that message in the catch block gives you far less information that you'd get if you printed the stack trace.  You might learn why there was a problem that way.

None of your connection, statement, or result set objects are cleaned up properly in this code.  You'll have no end of problems if you can ever get this to work once.

Are you really giving the root password in plain text?  Oh, my.

Why would you store a `Date` in a database as a `String` when you could have a `Date`?

You don't leverage connection pooling by acquiring the connection this way.  Even Tomcat will pool them for you.  Why wouldn't you want that?

Answer (score 0):

***your doing some mistake in your program, should must change following code like as:***

```
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/s3n","root","system");
    PreparedStatement cstmt= con.prepareStatement
("update windtariff_master set Owner=?, State=?, Date=?, Tariff=?, Discom=?" + 
   "where Site_ID=?");

 cstmt.setString(1, sowner); 
 cstmt.setString(2, sstate);
 cstmt.setString(3, sdate);
 cstmt.setString(4, stariff);
 cstmt.setString(5, sdiscom);
 cstmt.setString(6, ssiteid);
 cstmt.executeUpdate(); 
 out.println("updated successfully");
```